# Задержка в Javascript

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы после попадания пользователя на страничку, проходило несколько секунд, после он отправлялся дальше? Веря инету, это должно быть как то так, только почему-то не работает:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  Function reserve() {setTimeout(function() {
    Document.location.href('index.php');
}, 2000);}; reserve();

 </script>
</head>
<body onload="reserve();">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Заменил, ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть несколько ошибок: слово function и document пишутся с маленькой буквы. А так же document.location.href не является функцией, нужно использовать присвоение.

```
document.location.href = 'index.php';
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
 setTimeout(function() {
  document.location.href = 'index.php';
 }, 2000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Тут тоже несколько ошибок:
Вы создаете функцию, затем запускаете функцию, зачем запускается еще одна функция при загрузки страницы.

Comment: Может тут и есть ошибки, но оно работает! Спасибо, запомню свои фейлы)

Comment: @ВиталийЗаславский Спасибо за замечания, сейчас исправлю

Comment: @Darth Спасибо за правки в код

Answer (score 4):

Помимо того, что `function` и `document` пишутся с маленькой буквы, а `document.location.href` должен выглядеть так: `document.location.href = 'index.php';`, перенаправление лучше имитировать через `replace()`, тогда исходная страница не будет сохраняться в истории сеансов и пользователь не будет зацикливаться на бесконечных перенаправлениях при использовании кнопки `назад`.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var reserve = function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.replace('index.php');
      }, 2000);
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="reserve();">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function reserve() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log('worked')
        }, 2000);
      }
      reserve();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="reserve();">
    <input type="button" onclick="reserve();" value="Click me">
  </body>
</html>
```